# How to generate a unique identifier for each device?

Tags: ios

Hello everyone how to create a unique identifier for each iphone device of length 15 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually developers use *CFUUIDRef*

```
 CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

 NSString *uuidString = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL,uuidRef);

 CFRelease(uuidRef);
```

If you need exactly 15?

You can cut this string:

```
NSString *resultString = [uuidString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (0, 15)];
```

Comment: Hello thanks :) but its possible that when cutting it it can cause duplicate?

Comment: Of course it can, even not cut string can bu a duplicate, but the chance of it is so small that everyone ignores it.

Answer (score -1):

Apple announced some days ago that apps would be rejected if they keep using the old deprecated uniqueidentifier method:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

It must be changed to:

```
   CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
   CFStringRef uuidStr = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
   CFRelease(uuid);
```

Comment: Although this is unique, it isn't constant. Run it a couple of times and you won't get the same one. So it's utility as associating a user is limited as if the app gets removed and reinstalled, you'll have a completely new and different one.